# Question regarding qq plot of transformed data; what's the right transformation to use

Tags: spss, data-transformation, normality-assumption, skewness, qq-plot

So I will post qq of original data first along with logarthmic transformed data. If I'm interpreting the first correctly it looks like there is right skew to the data. The log transformed has a 'bulge' in the extreme right direction as well - values are lower than expected. I'm unsure how to transform this data to normal distribution. Does anyone have suggestion for other possible transformations I could try?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. The log transform has done a pretty good job. Is it possible that there is something interesting going on in the distribution of the lowest values? Sometimes you are better served by understanding the distribution than by transforming it in a complicated manner to make it 'ordinary'.